# how to pass Powershell script filepath from azure devops repo into Azure devops build pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have been following the article to learn Azure Devops. However, I am not able to get the file path for the Powershell script to pass into the azure devops build pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops

Below is my script in Azure Repo

[image]

Below is my Azure devops build pipeline, where I want to add the PowerShell script filepath:

[image]

The "ScriptPath" in the second image does not have a browse option, so I am unable to get the proper path.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'./HelloWorld.ps1' I had to use this format as a filepath.

Comment: Stackoverflow wont allow me to accept my answer for two days. I will mark it after two days.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Azure Devops is improving their user interface every day. The browse ellipse button at least showed up in my pipeline to edit the correct relative path to my Powershell script.

[image: Azure Devops - Piplines - Browse button]